# Add value to a ComboBox with button click

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have a combobox in a form and a button.
I want to add values to the combobox upon a click.
For example:
In the combobox there are 1,2,3,4 values present. I want to add 5 upon a button click.

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: @HansUp the combo box row source: valuelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use queries or tables as row sources.
In this case, I would just create a table with one column and set that as the row source for the combo box.

Now I can edit the data in the table at run-time as I like (delete some values, insert new values, copy values from other tables with a single query...) and when I'm done, I just call `Combo1.Requery`.

With this solution, the added values don't disappear after closing and reopening the form (not even after closing and reopening Access!), because the values are stored in a table in the Access database.

Answer (score 2):

Double click on your button to create an event handler for the click() event, then put this code in the event handler.  Replace Combo1 with the name of your combo.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

  Combo1.AddItem ("5")

End Sub
```

Comment: One problem, after closing the form and reopening it, the value added in the combobox disappears

Comment: Load your data when the form loads (or refresh your query).